# Event in DropDownList firing between different instances of user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, mvp

I have a custom user control with two DropDownLists. Each DropDownList has the Autopostback property set to true.

There is functionality to add a new instance of the user control and each new instance is inside a PlaceHolder control (in case it is needed, this design is based on [this answer from a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447883/repeater-and-custom-control-dynamically-adding-to-the-collection-and-retaining/14449305#14449305))

The problem I am having is that if I select an option from DropDownList A in instance 1 of the user control and then I select an option from DropDownList B in instance 2 of the user control, the OnSelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList A on instance 2 of the user control is fired as well with the same value that was selected on the same DropDownList from instance 1.

As an example let's say that the user control has information about cars and the two DropDownLists are color and year:

> - On the first instance of the user control I select the year 2010.
> - I DO NOT select a color in this first instance.
> - On the second instance of the user control I select the color Red.
> - I DO NOT select a year in this second instance.
> - The OnSelectedIndexChanged event of the "Year" DropDownList on the second instance gets fired with the value 2010.

Any insight of why this might be happening and how to fix it will really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your code and markup? It may be as simple as you've assigned the same eventhandler to both dropdowns ...

Comment: @5arx - I am trying to put together something that would reproduce the issue but, as it turns out it may be caused by a combination of a whole bunch of pieces that are involved: Model-View-Presenter, Update Panels, jQuery, nested user controls. This makes it very unpractical to post the code since I cannot determine which is the relevant one and to put everything is unfeasible (not to mention I would be violating the nondisclosure agreement with the customer). I will try to figure something out and post or upload somewhere a small solution. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I've added the `mvp` tag to your question in case its related to that.