# why a multiline textbox (inside a user control) is not holding its value after a postback?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that have a gridview, buttons and a multi-line textbox for comments.

When the page posts back, Gridview is **behaving** normaly (its controls keeps their values after postback). However, the **Comment** textbox is always empty, no matter what I do.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //This code is in the user ciontrol.
  if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     string test = this.txtDepartmentComments.Text;
   }

}
```

I put a break point at that line and the value is always empty. I've tried also to set the value in the code behind like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //This code is in the user ciontrol.
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     this.txtDepartmentComments.Text = "Test!";
   }
}
```

But when the page loads, the control remain empty.

Any idea why this is hapenning?

## EDIT

This the ascx code (i.e. user control)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" >
</asp:GridView>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Columns="45" TextMode= "MultiLine"/>
 <asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat="server" Text="Completed"/>
```

And thid id the aspx (i.e. the parent page)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpNewHire" runat="server">
       <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>            
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <user:MyUserControl ID = "MyUserControl1" runat = "server" 
                 DepartmentID= '<%# Eval("DepID")%>'><user:MyUserControl />
            </td>
        </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
       </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

if(!IsPostBack) is for reading values from controls after postback, you are trying to read text box value on initial load which will always be empty, remove the '!' from your condition. Also it is hard to debug your issue with out the aspx page contents, try posting the design part as well in your question.

**EDIT**

1. Your user tag is not well formatted inside repeater, it is missing closing tag and runat attribute

   ```
   <user:MyUserControl runat="server" ID = "MyUserControl1" DepartmentID= '<%# Eval("DepID")%>'></user:MyUserControl>
   ```
2. Controls inside repeater cannot be accessed directly, you have to loop through the rows of the repeater and find your child controls and then try reading values from them, that after you bind some data to the repeater.

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

Comment: I have added/removed if(!IsPostback), but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Page's `IsPostBack` and each user controls' `IsPostBack` are not same.

When a user control is posted back, that particular control's `IsPostBack` is true, but other user controls' `IsPostBack` are still false.

You can use explicitly `!Page.IsPostBack` inside a user control to check whether its parent page is posted back or not.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
   // do something
}
```

[Dynamically Loaded Control can not maintain values at PostBack?](http://geekswithblogs.net/chrishan/archive/2007/03/27/109988.aspx)  It is not directly related to your question, but it might be useful for you.

Comment: I'm now confused. Lol! As you can see in the code I posted above, the comment textbox is located inside a user control which in turn is located inside a repeater. When the page posts back, why the comment textbox is always empty in the code behind? Checking IsPostBack or Page.IsPostBack, is not making any difference. The textbox is still empty when I type something.

Comment: Anyway, even when when I type something, the textbox comes back empty after the postback.

Comment: Could you replace !IsPostBack with !Page.IsPostBack and see what happen? If it is still not working, could you post how GridView1 is populating with data?

Comment: I did replace !IsPostBack with !Page.IsPostBack, the result is still the same, i.e. (i) anything I type cannot be read in the code behind of the user control. (ii) When I set a value in the code behind of the user control for that textbox, It's not displayed when the page load.

Comment: How do you populate GridView1 with data? If you populate on every page load, all controls in the grid are rendered as new ones and all user entered data will be gone. Could you create a sample project at http://coderun.com/ide/

Comment: Here is another approach using placedholder instead of GridView - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14449305/296861